# How to add only index column in a given dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assume the dataframe looks like:

```
    Alpha   Num
0   A   65
1   B   66 
2   C   67 
3   D   68 
4   E   69 
5   F   70
```

Here index is from 0 to 5 and he sum of index column is 15.

So how to add the index only & get the sum 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.index.to_series().sum()
```